# Is the Shake Weight more effective than just using dumbbells?

Tags: medical-science, physical-fitness

On the Shake Weight [website](https://www.tryshakeweightclassic.com/#order), they claim:

> Shake Weight® Utilizes New Workout Technology Called Dynamic Inertia,
>   which can increase Muscle Activity to nearly 300% compared to a
>   Standard Dumbbell.*

The asterisk points to this text:

> *Study compared Shake Weight® to similar weight dumbbells performing standard dumbbell exercises.

Is there any evidence that indicates this might be true, or is it just marketing?

Comment: I'd be interested to know what their definition of 'Muscle Activity' is.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are referring to their paid "simulation" study, where someone made a model that predicted their machine works very well.

Comment: I know that South Park had results that met expectations... sorry I did it I Choose one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer seems to be no. I don't know if Consumer Reports is an OK reference for this site but they found it was not as effective as a typical workout.

> Bottom line
>
> Any resistance exercise can build strength. Yes, the routines on the DVDs that came with our
> Shake Weights can tire individual muscles.
> But for the chest, shoulder, and triceps, the Shake Weight's exercises
> were inferior to our conventional exercises targeting those muscles,
> and for the biceps, they were about the same. The Shake Weight
> routines burned fewer calories than our simple
> calisthenics-and-elastic-band routine—and fewer calories than walking
> at 3 mph.

http://www.consumerreports.org/cro/magazine-archive/2011/july/home-garden/shake-weight/overview/index.htm